# How can I position these buttons at the bottom of their container?

Tags: html, css

I've made a site that has a section containing a background image. I've added two buttons (`<a>` elements) to it and I want to position them to the bottom center of the section. Is that possible without relative/absolute positioning?

If, so, how please?

```css
.main-section {
    background-image: url('../IMG/main-section-logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 80vh;
    
}

.main-section:hover,:focus {
    transform:scale(1.015);
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.main-section:not(:hover) {
    transform:scale(1);
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.buttons {
    text-align: Center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-red {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1.3em 6.2em;
}

.btn-white {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1.3em 5em;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" class="btn-red">BUY NOW</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn-white">WATCH TRAILER</a>
        </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://flexboxfroggy.com/ Try this simple game, it will help you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

#### By using `flexbox`

1. `.container` must occupy the entire verticle space by using `height: 100%`
2. Add `flexbox` set of properties on `.container`

```
.main-section .container {
    height: 100%;
    display:  flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

3. Apply `auto` top margin to `.buttons`, which will automatically extend its specified margin to occupy the extra space in the flex container

```css
.main-section {
    background-image: url('../IMG/main-section-logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 80vh;
    
}

.main-section:hover,:focus {
    transform:scale(1.015);
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.main-section:not(:hover) {
    transform:scale(1);
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.main-section .container {
    height: 100%;
    display:  flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: Center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-red {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1.3em 6.2em;
}

.btn-white {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1.3em 5em;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" class="btn-red">BUY NOW</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-white">WATCH TRAILER</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so using flexbox.

Try the code below

```css
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

This should hopefully solve your problem.

Some resources to learn Flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
https://flexboxfroggy.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the justify-content: center did work, however, the buttons are not aligned on the bottom of the section.

Comment: Try using `align-self: flex-end;` on `buttons` then.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use flexbox on .main-section :

```
display: block;
```

Or

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Take a look at that https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Is it ok for you with flexbox?

Axel,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [place-items: end;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.main-section {
    background-image: url('../IMG/main-section-logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 80vh;
    
}

.main-section:hover,:focus {
    transform:scale(1.015);
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.main-section:not(:hover) {
    transform:scale(1);
    transition: 1s ease;
}

.buttons {
    text-align: Center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;/*Add this to get the elements centered*/
}

.btn-red {
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1.3em 6.2em;
}

.btn-white {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1.3em 5em;
}
/*have a look @ place-items: end;*/
.container{
    height: 90vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: end;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" class="btn-red">BUY NOW</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn-white">WATCH TRAILER</a>
        </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```css
     .buttons{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        align-items:flex-end;
        justify-content:center;
        }
```